# (change) or (ngModelChange) didn't work with hidden fields?

Tags: angular

i have a lookup component in `AngularJS 4` which updated a hidden `id` after selecting a value. I tried to add `(onModelChange)` and `(change)` event handlers to get change event when that hidden field get updated but either didn't work.

Here is my html :

```
<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="claimsReports.DealerId"  name="dealerId" (change)="saveParam($event,'DealerId')" />
```

I am not sure that change event get called on hidden field or not.

Comment: When do you expect the change or `ngModelChange` event of an hidden field to fire? There is no way a user can modify its content.

Comment: In my lookup component I am showing a grid view from where user can select any record and press select button. on pressing select button that dealerId got updated but it didn't fire change event

Comment: @RameshRajendran it is the comparison between both event handlers i am facing a rather different problem.

Answer (score 0):

in angular I would do:

```
<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="claimsReports.DealerId" 
   name="dealerId" (change)="saveParam($event)" />
```

and:

```
function saveParam(input){
   this.claimsReports.DealerId = input.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need for hidden fields in Angular. Instead, define a property in the component.

If you need to execute code when something else changes that property, use a getter and setter as shown below.

```
private _dealerId: number;
get dealerId(): number {
   return this._dealerId;
}
set dealerId(value: number) {
   this._dealerId = value;
   saveParam(value);
}
```

The setter will execute each time the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in template

```
<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="claimsReports.DealerId" 
   name="dealerId" (change)="saveParam($event.target.value)" />
```

in component.ts

```
saveParam(DealerId){
   let DealerId = DealerId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `type="hidden"`use `style="display: none;"`

angular events will act as normal.